# NoSuchMethodException was thrown when using reflection in Android

Tags: android, reflection

Suppose I have two interfaces `IUserManager` and `BBBB`  declared under package `android.os`:

```
package android.os;

public interface IUserManager  {
    void foo();
}
```

```
package android.os;


public interface BBBB {
    void foo();
}
```

Suppose I hope to use refection to get the `foo` methods defined in them:

```
line 1: BBBB.class.getDeclaredMethod("foo", new Class[] {});
line 2: IUserManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("foo", new Class[] {});
```

Why an exception `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.os.IUserManager.foo []` is thrown at line 2?